# Is there a way for excel to recognize which shape having macro assigned was clicked?

Tags: excel, vba

I have added a few shapes to my worksheet. I have assigned macros to them. But I had to create separate macros for all.

Is there a way for excel to recognize which shape was clicked and based on its text value find the cell to copy. That way I need not have to create separate macros for each shape.

I have tried searching for it online, found a few things which I tried but did not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Not sure but have a look at [Application.Caller](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the [Application.Caller property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.application.caller) can be used here.

```
Option Explicit 

Public Sub MyShapeMacro_Click()
    Dim CalledByShape As Shape
    Set CalledByShape = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller)

    'CalledByShape is your shape
    Debug.Print CalledByShape.OLEFormat.Object.Text 'returns the text of the shape
End Sub
```

Link this macro `MyShapeMacro_Click` to all your shapes.

Note this macro cannot be started in the VBA editor (it will throw an exception) it can only be run by clicking the shape.

Comment: I had tried the application.caller property but was getting error. So basically I want to get the name or the text inside of the shape which was clicked and then that value will be vlookuped to find the hyperlink associated with it.

Comment: @jafri What have you tried? And which error did you get? Please edit your original question to add this information. We cannot help if we don't see what you did wrong. • See my edited answer too.

Comment: sorry! I did not see your full code. Let me try it out. I will get back to you.

Comment: @PEH, it worked like a charm!. I guess I was not using application.caller property in the correct way. Thank you so much for helping me on this.